# Javascript mouse over on dynamic amount of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is on hover a p element contained inside an a tag gets bigger on hover. I have achieved this via css3 transitions, however this is not the issue.

A loop creates a variable amount of elements in the form below on each iteration.

```
anchorElement = "<a id='anchor" + countWide + "' class=\"boxOPT oneplustwo\" alt=\'"+   image_website +"' style=\"cursor:pointer;width:"+ itemWidth + "px"+";height:"+anchorHeight+";position:absolute;left:"+ locationLeft + "px"+";top:0.3%;\" ><p id=\"test\" class=\"popupDynamic\"> " + popupImageTitles[i] + "</p>";
        anchorElement += '</a>';
```

I would love to be able to add a mouse in/out effect whenever the user scrolls on the relevant anchor. each p tag contains unique information that needs to be conveyed and on hover only the relevant one should react.

I dont want to it it the below way, making two each of the methods every time a new element is created above. is there a way to have the following below which will work for a dynamic amount of elements?

```
$("#anchor" + etc).mouseover(function() {
document.getElementById("test").style.height="1.1em";
});
$("#anchor" + etc).mouseout(function() {
document.getElementById("test").style.height="1.1em";
});
```

My version of suggestions. the console logs works.

```
 .popupHighlight {
 color: red;
 }
```

..

```
 $('.boxOPToneplustwo').mouseover(function (e) {
console.log("in");
$(e.target).next('p').addClass("popupHighlight");
 });

 $('.boxOPToneplustwo').mouseout(function (e) {
$(e.target).next('p').removeClass("popupHighlight");
 });
```

Comment: Hey guys, the suggestion works well up to the point were the new class is added. It wont seem to apply the css changes for me. I will edit my answer above to show my code

Comment: Regarding your second issue: the html has a space in the classname `boxOPT oneplustwo`, but your selector doesn't: `$('.boxOPToneplustwo')`

Comment: for future reference, it's best off not to update with multiple questions, it's hard to keep track of what's going on. Maybe try asking a new question instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about selecting all a elements?

```
$('a').mouseout(function() {
 //do stuff in here
});
```

or better yet, have a class selector:

```
$('.mySpecialRolloverClass').mouseover(function (e) {
    $(e.target).next('p').addClass("highlight");
});

$('.mySpecialRolloverClass').mouseout(function (e) {
    $(e.target).next('p').removeClass("highlight");
});
```

which would go hand in hand with

```
<a href="whatever" class="mySpecialRolloverClass">An anchor</a>
```

and

```
.highlight {
    color:red;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8J6kM/

Comment: Remember if anything adds later to the page, they won't get any of these events. Using `on` method could be a safer choice.

Comment: yep, definitely worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

The [@yochannah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542891/yochannah) answer is correct, however if you want to add more links dynamically, you then need to use `on` method instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`, otherwise it won't work. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8J6kM/2/) and jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for further details.

```
// I assumed that links are placed inside of a container element: #links
$('#links').on('mouseover', '.mySpecialRolloverClass', function (e) {
    $(e.target).next('p').addClass("highlight");
});
```